# Bookmark contents in android

Tags: android

I have a requirement to do bookmarking in the app .How to do bookmark in android app.
Is it possible to do with shared preferences or is there any better way.

Comment: Please explain what your app does, what you mean by "bookmarking", and what you've already tried (if anything).

Comment: there are lots of pages in the app. whenever they like a page they can bookmark it and can comeback to the particular page by using the bookmarked value

Answer (score 1):

There are several [approaches](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to store persistent app data in Android.
Shared preferences are suitable to store app settings and state of UI.
For any kind of bookmarks better to use SQLite database.